# Flutter MaterialApp isn't accepting translation paramater

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using flutter 2 and trying to use GetX for localization between two different languages.

problem is I should put my translation class in main.dart, inside MaterialApp. but MaterialApp isn't accepting that paramater. do I need to upgrade to flutter 3 or where is the problem?

My Code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
]);
return ScreenUtilInit(
    designSize: Size(411.429, 
    835.8095238095239),
    minTextAdapt: true,
    builder: (context, child) {
      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
               textTheme: 
               GoogleFonts.josefinSansTextTheme(
                Theme.of(context).textTheme),
            primaryColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
            primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
            visualDensity: 
         VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
        home: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: AppConfigPage(),
        ),
        locale: Get.deviceLocale,
        translations: MyLocale() // here is the problem .. with "tranalsations" paramater.

      );
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I am using MaterialApp, correct to use GetMaterialApp